# Delphi Listbox Item name, no caption

Tags: delphi, listbox

I add items to listbox:

```
for i:=0 to HomeWorkers.Count-1 do
begin
s := '['+HomeWorker[i].Id+']  ' + HomeWorker[i].Name;
Listbox1.Items.Add(s);
end;
```

Now i want to get number of selected item. 
I can get its caption:

```
ShowMessage(ListBox1.Items.Strings[Listbox1.ItemIndex]);
```

Example id`s: 12880345, 1274136.
Can I add Item with

```
'['+HomeWorker[i].Id+']  ' + HomeWorker[i].Name;
```

, but in ShowMessage display only HomeWorker[i].Id without string caption parsing? Thanks in advance.
P.S I am from Russia, so sorry for bad English

Comment: Please improve your question by stating clearly what your inputs are and what your desired outputs are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the IDs in the `Objects` property, just typecast from `Integer` to `TObject`:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddObject(Format('[%d] %s', [Homeworker.ID, Homeworker.Name]),
  TObject(Homeworker.ID));
```

and later you can retrieve it, typecasting back:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Integer(ListBox1.Items.Objects[ListBox1.ItemIndex])));
```

Comment: Homeworker.ID looks like a string to me, at least in the code from the question.

Comment: @David: There is no Homeworker.ID in the question. Homeworker[i].Id does look like a string, though. The loop iterates over Homeworkers, though. To me it seems like pseudo-code, not to be taken literally.

Comment: Why not TObject(Homeworker[i]) since the ID is superfluous in that case, and Homeworker[x] IS an object?

Comment: @Warren: Sure, if it's an object, why not? However, from the code it's not clear what `Homeworkers` or `Homeworker[i]` is.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to extract the Id from the formatted text that you put into the list box. If I'm correct, you can do it like this:

```
function GetIdFromListBoxText(const Text: string): string;
var
  P1, P2: Integer;
begin
  P1 := Pos('[', Text);
  P2 := Pos(']', Text);
  if (P1<>0) and (P2<>0) then
    Result := Copy(Text, P1+1, P2-P1-1)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

This code relies on an assumption that your Id strings do not contain `[` or `]`.

You can use it in your code like this:

```
ShowMessage(GetIdFromListBoxText(ListBox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex]));
```

Comment: It is a listbox caption parsing. I want to make different names to listbox items and get this names with ItemIndex. For example: Listbox.Items.Add('Hello world!') with name 'example' and if i ShowMessage(something[Listbox1.ItemIndex)] i want to get 'example'.

Comment: @Anton That comment sounds like a completely different question.

Comment: Well, I clearly can't understand your question and your comment doesn't seem to match your question. Perhaps someone else will have better luck working out what you mean.  In your question you add `[ID] Name`, but now you just want to add `Name`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might answer his question, if I am getting it right? He is pulling the item in his example, when he should be showing his object instead.

Try this:

```
showmessage(string(listbox1.items.object[listbox1.itemindex]));
```

in place of:

```
ShowMessage(ListBox1.Items.Strings[Listbox1.ItemIndex]);
```